# Which ways are there to decouple deployment from release?

Tags: deployment, release-management, feature-toggles

One method of continuous deployment is to decouple deployment from release, i.e. deploy updates without activating the changes immediately.

I know that [feature-toggles](/questions/tagged/feature-toggles) can be used for this, but I'm wondering if there are other techniques for "non-features".

For example, would you build a feature toggle for a bugfix? Probably not and one could argue that bugfixes should be deployed as soon as possible, because it can only get better. And after a bugfix has been released, I sure don't want to toggle it off anymore.
But is this the case? It might be a risky change that you want to release in a controlled way. And if there *are* unexpected side effects, it's good to be able to roll it back. So, feature flags for every change?

And what about visual changes? For example, can you implement something like a feature flag in CSS? Does it even make sense?

Comment: Pete Hodgson wrote extensively about the various categories of feature toggles, including bugfixes, and other situations where those are suitable. https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html

Answer (score 7):

For software in the web app category, depending on you infra/hosting provider such decoupling *might* be possible to switch incoming traffic across (or split it between) different deployed versions of the sw, practically covering any of the changes you mention: bugfixes, visuals, etc.

Such support would typically not require feature toggles. And it might be applicable regardless of the app being monolithic or split in microservices.

For example Google's [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) Paas offering has support for traffic splitting and migration.

From [Splitting Traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/splitting-traffic):

> You can use traffic splitting to specify a percentage distribution of
>   traffic across two or more of the versions within a service. Splitting
>   traffic allows you to conduct [A/B testing](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) between your versions
>   and provides control over the pace when rolling out features.

From [Migrating Traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrating-traffic):

> Traffic migration switches the request routing between the versions
>   within a service of your application, moving traffic from one or more
>   versions to a single new version.

Answer (score 5):

While with monoliths you might be restricted to switches, with microservice architectures, you can split every deployment pool of nodes providing a service (ie. pods). You then activate the deployment of the newly changed product in a subset of pool, and carefully monitor it; you can even choose which amount of the pool to deploy the change to, say for instance, activate the change for 15% of the traffic. You might find the feature called "rolling update" in literature.